# error line 1 ! File ended while scanning use of \caption@xdblarg

Tags: errors, line

I have this problem: My document was running well and from one moment to another I had this problem in the line 1:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \caption@xdblarg.
<inserted text>\par<> 
./intento4.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop.
```

My program start just like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %acento sin codigo
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite} % para contraer referencias
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{titling}
...
```

An I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: presumably the problem is a `\caption` in `intento4.tex` try to make a small example with just a `\caption` from that file that shows the error, and post the example here

Comment: I'd run into the same problem, not with this nice error message, but the  `@xdblarg` was contained. As faulty was a line marked which had an `\input` Statement. This one was correct, but in the actually input I forgot to close a `\section{Where left I my head`

Comment: The problem is a missing '}', search in your .tex file and find it.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated by users in the comment section, this is most likely due to a missing closing bracket `}`.
In my case, I had an opened caption statement that I didn't close.

```
\caption{Some long text without closing bracket.
```